# Merge Sort optimization

Tags: c#, sorting, mergesort

I was looking at other people code and I realized that mine is not so neat after all.

In this version, I included a base case for the merge part (when there is only 2 elements to merge, just sort it normally). I do not know this is a good idea or not, never seen it in other people' codes.

This is the first time I implemented this algorithm.  I hope you can help me out with this code so it could look more readable.

```
class MergeSort
{
    public static void Standard() {
        int[] A = new int[] {234, 31, 41, 59, 26, 41, 58, 90, 103, 14, 1235, 2134, 12, 673, 234, 234, 64, 23, 132, 432, 123};
        int last_Index = A.Length-1;

        SplitMerge(A, 0, last_Index);
        foreach (int i in A)
            Console.Write(i + " ");
    }

    //Here is the recursive split merge
    private static void SplitMerge(int[] A,int iBegin,int iEnd) {
        //Base case. Every  recursive has a base case
        if (iBegin == iEnd) return;

        //Calculate the middle index here. This work for odd number array.
        int Middle = (int)Math.Floor((double)(iEnd + iBegin)/2);

        //split left
        SplitMerge(A, iBegin, Middle);

        //split right
        SplitMerge(A, Middle+1, iEnd);

        //merge left and right
        MergeLeftRight(A, iBegin, Middle, iEnd);

    }

    //This is the merge
    private static void MergeLeftRight(int[] A, int iBegin, int iMid, int iEnd) {
        //If we are comparing just 2 numbers, just compare them already xD
        if (iBegin == iMid) {
            int temp_Num = A[iBegin];
            if (A[iBegin] >= A[iEnd]) {
                A[iBegin] = A[iEnd];
                A[iEnd] = temp_Num;
            }
            return;
        }

        //Create a temporary list to store numbers
        List<int> temp = new List<int> {};

        //Declare the last index of left array, we will go to this but will not pass this
        int left_End = iMid;

        //Same as above. This is for the right array
        int right_End = iEnd;               

        //Left array start from iBegin, but Right array must start fron left_End+1
        iMid++;

        //Check the number in left and right arrays and sort them while both array still has elements inside
        while ((iBegin <= left_End) && (iMid <= right_End)) {
            if (A[iBegin] <= A[iMid]) {
                temp.Add(A[iBegin]);
                iBegin++;
            }
            else {
                temp.Add(A[iMid]);
                iMid++;
            }
        }

        //If right array is empty, add all leftover elements from left array to the list
        while (iBegin <= left_End) {
            temp.Add(A[iBegin]);
            iBegin++;
        }

        //Same as above loop. Add all leftover elements from right array to the list.
        while (iMid <= right_End) {
            temp.Add(A[iMid]);
            iMid++;
        }

        //Put everything back in the original array, merge everything. Since we are going from right to left
        //We need to reverse the List.
        temp.Reverse();
        foreach (int i in temp) {
            A[iEnd] = i;
            iEnd--;
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're asking for a [readability](/questions/tagged/readability) review, here's my input:

- **Way too many comments**. Comments should say *why*, not *what* - the *code itself* should describe what it's doing.
- **Use XML comments to describe methods**. `// regular comments` only work if you're looking at the method's code. When you're *using* the code, XML comments are picked up by Visual Studio and you get tooltips to help you correctly use the method. For example:

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// A recursive split merge method. 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="A">The array to be sorted.</param>
  /// <param name="iBegin">The lower bound index for the sub-array to be sorted.</param>
  /// <param name="iEnd">The upper bound index for the sub-array to be sorted.</param>
  private static void SplitMerge(int[] A, int iBegin, int iEnd)
  ```
- **Avoid Hungarian Notation**. Prefixing `i` for `int` types is useless in .net, and hinders readability. `iBegin` and `iEnd` should simply be `begin` and `end` to be correct, `startIndex` and `endIndex` to be meaningful.
- **Use camelCase for parameters and locals**. Parameter `A` should be `a`... but that's an awfully bad name. `unsortedArray`, or simply `unsorted`, would be much more descriptive.
- **Avoid snake_case**. C# naming conventions don't encourage the use of an underscore (`_`) in the middle of an identifier's name. Use *camelCase* for parameters and locals, and *PascalCase* for types and public members (actually, *exposed* is more accurate, since `internal` and `protected` members should also be *PascalCase*).
- **Avoid Java-style curly braces**. Not to start any flamewars, but C# conventions put the opening brace `{` on the next line.
- **Method names should start with a verb**. `Standard()` isn't a good method name. Since it's a member of a class named `MergeSort`, `Sort()` would probably be best, and should take the array in as a parameter to be any useful...